# Reactive Extensions IObservable notify when subscribers subscribe

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have a `Subject<T>` and I want to be notified when something subscribes to it. I cannot find a mechanism for this. Am I missing something?

For example:

```
    public class AccountManager
    {
        private ReplaySubject<string> _accountEvents = new ReplaySubject<string>();

        public AccountManager()
        {
        }

        public void Add(string val)
        {
            _accountEvents.OnNext(val);
        }

        public IObservable<string> AccountEvents { get { return _accountEvents.AsObservable<string>(); } }

    }
```

Can `AccountManager` be notified when any other code calls `Subscribe` on the `AccountEvents` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either this

```
        var subj = new Subject<string>();
        var o = Observable.CreateWithDisposable<string>(observer =>
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("subscribed");
                                                return subj.Subscribe(observer);
                                            });
```

or (similar to Scott's answer)

```
        var o = Observable.Defer(() =>
                                     {
                                         Console.WriteLine("subscribed");
                                         return subj;
                                     });
```

In the first case you have more freedom, since you have an observer passed in as a parameter, so in addition to routing subject output to the observer you can call observer.OnNext, OnError, OnComplete when your logic demands it.

Comment: If you are using CreaetWithDisposable, it's almost worth skipping the subject entirely unless you need the functionality of a subject subclass.

Comment: I am trying to make this work. I am not able to see the Console.WriteLine("subscribed"); fire at all. Even, when subscribing to "o", I only see it fire once, even when subscribing to the subject several times.

Comment: @doanir Then you are doing something incorrectly - because I see the "subscribed" output on each subscription in both cases. Try to post the test function you use.

Comment: @Sergey Got it. Works now. I was subscribing on subj instead of "o"

Comment: Now, I have to figure out how to get notified of disposed subscriptions. :)

Comment: @doanair Then the first case is better. Create your own wrapper around Subject that also implements IDisposable and return it instead of subj.Subscribe;

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly all, but could possibly be made to work

```
var subj = new Subject<string>();
var io = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return("Subscribed")
                                          .Do(Console.WriteLine))
                   .Concat(subj);
 io.Subscribe();
```